# Have a C++ variable able to be either Class Foo or Class Bar

Tags: c++, c++11

I am interested to write a printer to output two different formats. Let's call them txt and csv.

Can something like below be implemented in C++?

```
class Printer {
public:
  virtual void header() = 0;
};

class CSV : Printer {
public:
 void header() { printf("csv\n"); }
};

class TXT : Printer {
public:
 void header() { printf("txt\n"); }
};

int decider(int type) {
  auto prt;
  if (type == 1) {
     prt = new CSV;
  } else {
     prt = new TXT;
  }
  prt.header();
}
```

If not, what's an alternative to doing something similar?

Comment: `auto` requires initialization for type deduction.

Comment: The design pattern is known as "factory method"

Comment: Operator `new` returns a pointer. Each call to `new` must have a matching call to `delete`!!

Comment: In order for this to work correctly (without either a leak or undefined behavior), you will need a [virtual destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/10077) in `Printer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `auto` you'd want a pointer to the base class

```
int decider(int type) {
  Printer* prt;
  if (type == 1) {
     prt = new CSV;
  } else {
     prt = new TXT;
  }
  prt->header();
}
```

but instead of raw pointers and `new` (since you are leaking memory from a missing `delete`) I'd instead use smart pointers here

```
#include <memory>

int decider(int type) {
  std::unique_ptr<Printer> prt;
  if (type == 1) {
     prt = std::make_unique<CSV>();
  } else {
     prt = std::make_unique<TXT>();
  }
  prt->header();
}
```

As noted by @FredLarson you also need a virtual destructor in your base class

```
class Printer {
public:
  virtual ~Printer() = default;
  virtual void header() = 0;
};
```

you should also inherit publicly from the base class

```
class CSV : public Printer { 
  ...
};

class TXT : public Printer {
  ...
};
```

Comment: You can't say `prt.header` in this code.  Either change `prt` to `prt_p` and after the if statement make a `Printer& prt`, or change the last line to `prt->header`.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

Comment: I believe `Printer` will need a virtual destructor to avoid UB here.

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way:

```
void decider(int type) {
  std::unique_ptr<Printer> prt{};
  if (type == 1) {
     prt = std::make_unique<CSV>();
  } else {
     prt = std::make_unique<TXT>();
  }
  prt->header();
}
```

Comment: I believe `Printer` will need a virtual destructor to avoid UB here.

Comment: Extensions: Consider returning the `unique_ptr` rather than calling the `header` function. This will allow you to reuse `decider` for similar tasks in the future.  Also consider using an `enum` for the type rather than an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this kind of polymorphism is possible.
Here is a runnable example based on yours:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class Printer {
public:
  virtual void header() {};
};

class CSV : public Printer {
public:
 void header() { printf("csv\n"); }
};

class TXT : public Printer {
public:
 void header() { printf("txt\n"); }
};

int decider(int type) {
  Printer* prt;
  if (type == 1) {
     prt = new CSV();
  } else {
     prt = new TXT();
  }
  prt->header();
}

int main() {

    int type = 1;

    decider(type);

    type = 0;

    decider(type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about passing the required type as template parameter?

I mean something as

```
template <typename T>
void decider ()
 {
   auto prt = new T;
   prt.header();

   delete prt;
 }
```

that you can call as follows

```
decider<CSV>();
decider<TXT>();
```

As pointed by Daniel H (thanks!) this only works if you know the type compile-time; if the type (`CSV` or `TXT`) is decided run-time, this solution is impracticable.

Comment: That decides at compile time not runtime.